# Topological entropy of a circle rotation

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems

I am trying to understand the concept of topological entropy as defined by 
$h_{top} (f) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log(sep(n, \epsilon, f))$, where $sep(n,\epsilon,f)$ is the maximum cardinality of an $(n,\epsilon)$-spanning set, which can be replaced with minimum spanning set cardinality or the minimum covering set cardinality. Especially the $\epsilon$ limit causes some problems when i try to actually determine the entropy of a map.

For instance, the circle rotations $R_{\alpha}:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$, defined as $R_{\alpha}(x) = x+\alpha \mod 1$, should have entropy 0. However, if I am correct, the set $\{\epsilon, 2\epsilon, \ldots, 1\}$ is an $(n,\epsilon)$-seperated set with cardinality $\frac{1}{\epsilon}$ when $\epsilon = 1/c$ for some $c \in \mathbb{R}$. Since the circle rotation does not change the distance between points, $sep(n,\epsilon,f) = sep(1,\epsilon,f)$. But now the entropy is
$$
h(R_{\alpha}) = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log(sep(1, \epsilon, f)) \geq \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+} \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{-\log(\epsilon)}{n}.
$$
I do not see how to show that the entropy should be 0. In fact, I do not even see or understand why it is true in this case. How should i continue? Find a different spanning/covering/seperating set?

Comment: If you want a upper bound, use the "minimum cardinality of a covering set" definition.

Comment: Then inserting $2\epsilon$ for the "minimum cardinality of a covering set" would give me an upper bound, right? The limit stays the same, so does that mean the limit in my original question is in fact 0? I did not think that I could simply let $\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow 0^+}\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \frac{-\log(\epsilon)}{n} = 0$.

Comment: Yes, the limit would be 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! Question answered.